# Import vtk file in grass or qgis

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, land-survey, vtk

last summer I made the relief of a cave, and at this time I returned with Therion software. This survey is in 3d and I can save it in the formats .Lox, .3d, vtk.
I would like to import it in grass or qgis, software that I know better than others. I can not find the command that allows me to do so. Can anyone suggest me something?[image]

Comment: Have you read these two pages yet? You can use ParaView and Meshlab to process your .vtk files for Grass: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Help_with_3D#Vector_3D_polygons and http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Triangle_Mesh#ParaView

Comment: Hi @Filippo, could you please post your solution as an answer? This could help others who have similar problems.

Comment: Ji, Yes. I posed the question to the forum because I was interested in calculating the volume of the cave.
Using the operating system and software debian paraview and MeshLab can be found directly within the repository.
The options of statistical calculation I found in paraview (the hours I have to apply).
I also read this page wiki http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Paraview is an excellent solution to my needs.
Are the signs that I needed.

Comment: Hello, I finished the first step. This is the procedure I used to calculate the volume of the cave:
1) drawing survey with therion
2) Displaying the file viewer therion
3) Export the 3D model created in vtk format (you also write
the file extension)
4) I open Paraview software and open the file vtk
5) Save the file as .x3d
6) I open MeshLab software
7) I open the file x3d
8) I apply the filter: Filters -> Quality measure and computation ->
compute geometric Measures
9) I open the log window: View -> Show Layer dialog
10) I read the lines Volume Mesh and Mesh Surface